# Sacar estructura de todas las tablas SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Con la siguiente `SELECT` veo todas las tablas de un usuario:

```
SELECT table_name FROM all_tables where owner='usuario1'
```

Resultado:

```
TABLE_NAME
----------
USUARIOS
PRODUCTOS
CLIENTES
...(+300 tablas)
```

Y con la sentencia `describe` veo la estructura de una tabla:

```
describe productos;
```

Resultado:

```
PRODUCTOS
Nombre               Nulo     Tipo           
-------------------- -------- -------------- 
id_productos         NOT NULL  NUMBER(5)
nombre_producto                VARCHAR2(255)
...
```

---

¿Cómo podria unir estas dos funcionalidades?

Necesito sacar la estructura de todas las tablas que son casi 400 tablas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar [`dmbs_metadata.get_ddl`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885):

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name, owner)
from all_tables
where owner = 'usuario1'
```